# How to check whether it is a Saturday and Sunday respectively in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I would like to check whether it is Saturday and Sunday in MATLAB. I know there is a function called `busday` in MATLAB to check whether it is a business day but I would like to check whether it is Saturdays or Sunday respectively so that I find the corresponding Monday, which I need in my calculation.

Need some guidance on how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `weekday` function:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/weekday.html

```
D = '21-Dec-2012';
[DayNumber,DayName] = weekday(D)
DayNumber =

     6

DayName =

Fri
```